# Detecting the add link confirm event in trix editor

Tags: javascript, html, trix

When making a hyperlink from a text with the trix-editor I have altered the pattern so www.website.com is acceptable for convenience. I now have to add https:// to all those links to make them valid. This is why I want to be able to know when someone is confirming a hyperlink to be able to add https:// to the link if it is "www." only.